# Errors when preprocesssing lat/long for gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have an existing amount of Users which didn't have latitude or longitude. After adding the gem, I wanted to preprocess latitude and longitude fields by doing this:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  geo_data = Gmaps4rails.geocode(user.gmaps4rails_address)
  user.update_attributes(latitude: geo_data[0][:lat], longitude: geo_data[0][:lng])
  sleep(1)
end
```

But when doing so, sometimes, when my address is wrong, I get a message like this:

```
The address you passed seems invalid, status was: ZERO_RESULTS.
Request was: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&address=asdasdsa, mountain, US&sensor=false
```

This makes my rake to break, so I am wondering how can I just set latitude and longitude for those addresses which are correct and just ignore (not set lat/long) for those that return an error like the above?

EDIT:

I have tried to do this:

```
    User.all.each do |user|
      begin
        geo_data = Gmaps4rails.geocode(user.gmaps4rails_address)
      rescue
        next
      end
      user.update_attributes(latitude: geo_data[0][:lat], longitude: geo_data[0][:lng])
      sleep(1)
    end
```

But no luck. I can't catch the exception and go to next in the loop.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't catch the exception"?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  begin
    geo_data = Gmaps4rails.geocode(user.gmaps4rails_address)
    user.update_attributes(latitude: geo_data[0][:lat], longitude: geo_data[0][:lng])
    sleep(1)
  rescue
    #just prevent loop from crash
  end
end
```